# Nvidia installing

Tags: nvidia, xorg, software-installation

Trying to install Nvidia .run drivers to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop version

But X server is up and has a lock to prevent concurent installations.

I think I should switch in mode 1 or so to shut off X11 but I cannot manage to do so ...

Having read lots of documentation saying switch to console mode Ctrl-Alt-F1, ... , but when I kill X11 process, it re-starts automaticaly, whith no end

Answer (score 0):

You can install accelerated Nvidia driver `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` from main repo:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop the Display Manager.
As far as I understand then different distributions there own Display Manager.
On Kubuntu as I am running it's called Lightdm.

To stop it go to console mode 
Login using your user name and password.

Stop the lightdm service by:

```
$> sudo service stop lightdm
```

Install the Nvidia driver and start the lightdm service by

```
$> sudo service stop lightdm
```

I can't recommend install NVidia's own driver from there web site as I haven't had very good experience with the driver. Instead go to the system settings and install the latest driver using the Additional Drivers app.